# Upload local file to sever SFTP via curl php

Tags: php, file-upload, curl, ftp

I am trying to implement upload local file to server via sftp curl method but facing File upload error. Error number: 7.

Here is my code.

```
<?php

$ourFileName = "/var/www/html/example.com/100092923.csv";

$fpSend = fopen($ourFileName, 'r');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "sftp://example:@example/confirm/" . $ourFileName);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 22);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE, '/var/www/html/example.com/newcsv/ddd.ppk');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE, '/var/www/html/exmple.com/newcsv/ddd.pub');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSH_AUTH_TYPES, CURLSSH_AUTH_PUBLICKEY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
$fp = fopen($ourFileName, 'r');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($ourFileName));
curl_exec($ch);


fclose($fpSend);

$error_no = curl_errno($ch);

if ($error_no == 0) {
    $error = 'File uploaded succesfully.';
} else {
    $error = 'File upload error. Error number: ' . $error_no;
}

if (curl_error($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);

}
echo $error;
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

let me know if any one has a solution to our problem.

Answer (score 0):

> cURL Error (7): couldn't connect to host

This would suggest the connection is being blocked. Using a non standard port for ssh/sftp can do this.

Are you able to connect via sftp using a standard ftp client like filezilla? Rule out connection details issue before looking at your code.

A quick look over your code and everything looks fine.

Comment: thanks for your answer but if i use Filezilla then its working fine but if i try via curl then only . above issue arised.